# Erro de acesso ao chamar página de login - PHP Generator

Tags: php, mysql

Recentemente a `locaweb` fez uma manutenção em seus servidores e depois disso algumas páginas de nossa hospedagem pararam de funcionar, uso um framework chamado `PHP Generator` para MySQL [Site do Desenvolvedor do Framework](https://www.sqlmaestro.com/products/mysql/phpgenerator/) e quando tento acessar a página de login para efetuar alguma manutenção recebo essa mensagem de erro:

```
PHP Warning:  call_user_func_array() [function.call-user-func-array]: First argument is expected to be a valid callback, 'Global_GetCustomTemplateHandler' was given in E:\home\imobiliariafusco\Web\admin\components\utils\event.php on line 44
```

Esse acesso estava funcionando normalmente antes das manutenções, depois disso o erro começou a ser mostrado, localmente o acesso é feito normalmente, minha pergunta é, isso é problema de configuração do php.ini? O suporte da locaweb não conseguiu resolver o problema.

Comment: Verifique as versões do php.

Comment: Olá @rray, obrigado pela dica, a versão do php que tenho localmente é a 5.3.5 e a da locaweb 5.2.7, portanto a minha é superior.

Comment: Pode colocar o código ou a função que está dando erro? o php5.2 não tem suporte a funções anonimas.

Comment: Não tem log da manutenção disponível pro cliente? Eles podem ter mexido na versão do MySQL também, visto que esse framework parece ser um gerador automatizado de ORM.

Comment: Olá @AlanMachado, exatamente é um gerador automático de ORM